# Animation wpf - Show for n seconds then fade out

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

I have a storyboard with one `DoubleAnimation` this animates the opacity from 1 to 0 in one second:

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NotificationStackPanel"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="1"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

The fade-out animation is pretty quick, and that's the purpose. But how can I make an animation to show the control for n seconds **then** start this fade-out animation?

I tried by making a new DoubleAnimation on top of the current one, with values `From="1"` and `To="1"` and a `Duration="5"`, but that did seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply set the `DoubleAnimation` `BeginTime` property to the value you need.

Comment: Ofc, just need to wait 10 min or so.